# Finding area in image with maximum variation of pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am struggling with some algorithm to extract the region from an image which has the maximum change in pixels. I got the following image after preprocessing. 
[image]

I did following steps of pre-processing

```
x = imread('test2.jpg');
gray_x = rgb2gray(x);
I = medfilt2(gray_x,[3 3]);
gray_x = I;

%%
canny_x = edge(gray_x,'canny',0.3);
figure,imshow(canny_x);

%%
s = strel('disk',3);
si = imdilate(canny_x,s);
%figure5
figure; imshow(si);
se = imerode(canny_x,s);title('dilation');
%figure6
figure; imshow(se);title('Erodsion');
I = imsubtract(si,se);
%figure7
figure; imshow(I);
```

Basically what I am struggling for, is to make weapon detection system using Image processing. I want to localize possible area's to be weapon so that I could feed them to my classifier to identify if it is a weapon or not. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: What does “maximum change in pixels” mean? Are you asking for regions where the pixel values change frequently from neighbor to neighbor? Why are those more likely to contain a weapon?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

- Find corner points in the image (Harris corner points, etc)
- Set value of all the corner points to white while remaining image will be black
- Take a rectangular window and traverse it over the whole image
- sum all the white pixels in that rectangular window
- select that region whose sum is maximum of all regions

Comment: sounds like moving average window? doesn't it make too slow the whole process?

Comment: @AbdulRehman: a moving average is very cheap, at least if it is with a rectangular window. Compared to the Harris detector, it’s not a cost to worry about.